# BrowserslistError when building Angular5 library

Tags: angular, npm, angular5

So I'm building an Angular library, and I'm having some trouble setting up my automated build environment. This is my folder setup:

```
my-app/
..my-lib/
....package.json
..package.json
```

I need to build `my-lib` first before running `npm install` under `my-app`. The reason being, I can't just do `npm install` in the `my-app` directory, because it is referencing the `file:my-lib/dist` which doesn't exist until I build `my-lib`. I could just remove this line during in my check-in, and always add it locally when testing, but I'd rather keep it in to make it more streamlined.

In the main app's `package.json` I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "my-lib": "file:my-lib/dist",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^3.0.6",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.32.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
}
```

And in my `lib`'s `package.json` I have:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": ">=5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6"
},
"dependencies": {
    "<externalDependency>": "^1.0.0",
},
```

What I want to do with my build system is:

1. Install Dev Dependencies of `my-app`
2. Install Peer Dependencies `my-lib`
3. `ng-packagr` build `my-lib`
4. `npm install` for `my-app`

Originally, I had these steps:

- `cd my-app`
- `npm install --only=dev` // Install devDependencies
- `npm install <manually put all my-lib peerDependencies>`
- `cd my-lib`
- `npm install --prefix ../` // install external dependency into my-app node-modules
- `cd ..`
- `ng-packagr -p my-lib/package.json`

However, the build fails here with error:

```
Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")`
```

I had this issue before locally, but I was able to delete the `browserslist` file to get this to work. However, on the build machine, I'm not sure where this file is. Is there anything I need to do to get this to build successfully?

Comment: why not use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr)?

Comment: I am using that? I realized I messed up one of the ng-packagr commands in the post above, so I've edited the correct command I am running.